# 404 from websvn configuration on apache

Tags: apache-2.4, svn

I'm trying to setup websvn on Raspberry Pi using apache. In /etc/apache2/conf.d/websvn I have the following configuration:

```
# Configuration for websvn using php4.

Alias /websvn /usr/share/websvn

<Directory /usr/share/websvn>
  ## No MultiViews
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Options FollowSymLinks
  ## MultiViews
  #DirectoryIndex wsvn.php
  #Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  ## End MultiViews
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  <IfModule mod_php4.c>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
    php_flag track_vars On
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

But when I try to connect to http://.../websvn I get the error 404. In the apache log I read (I had to bump the log level):

```
[Sat May 14 12:17:52.737294 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 652] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 79.54.45.40:51893] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sat May 14 12:17:52.738726 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 652] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 79.54.45.40:51893] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sat May 14 12:17:52.741081 2016] [core:info] [pid 652] [client 79.54.45.40:51893] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/websvn
```

So I suppose the problem is that it is trying to route to /var/www/html/websvn, which does not exist at all. Instead I suppose it should read from /usr/share/websvn, like that alias. Any idea why this may be happening? I grepped the entire /etc directory and I found no occurrence of the string "/var/www/html/websvn".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was related to the fact that websvn conf file was placed in /etc/apache2/conf.d instead of /etc/apache2/modules-enabled. Just symlinking from modules-enabled fixed the problem.